# Survival analysis in PyMC 3

Tags: pymc, survival-analysis

I tried to port simple survival model [from here (the first one in introduction)](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/fonnesbeck/Bios366/blob/master/notebooks/Section4_3-Introduction-to-PyMC.ipynb) form PyMC 2 to PyMC 3. However, I didn't find any equivalent to "observed" decorator and my attempt to write a new distribution failed. Could someone provide an example how is this done in PyMC 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a tricky port, and requires three new concepts:

1. Use of the `theano` tensor
2. Use of the `DensityDist`
3. Passing a `dict` as `observed`

This code provides the equivalent model as the PyMC2 version you linked to above:

```python
import pymc3 as pm
from pymc.examples import melanoma_data as data
import theano.tensor as t

times = data.t # not to be confused with the theano tensor t!
failure = (data.censored==0).astype(int)

with pm.Model() as model:

    beta0 = pm.Normal('beta0', mu=0.0, tau=0.0001)
    beta1 = pm.Normal('beta1', mu=0.0, tau=0.0001)
    lam = t.exp(beta0 + beta1*data.treat)

    def survival_like(failure, value):
        return t.sum(failure * t.log(lam) - lam * value)

    survive = pm.DensityDist('survive', survival_like,
                        observed={'failure': failure, 'value': times})

with model:

    start = pm.find_MAP()
    step = pm.NUTS(scaling=start)
    trace = pm.sample(10000, step=step, start=start)

pm.traceplot(trace);
```

Output as follows:

[image]

Comment: When passing `observed={...}`, how are the arguments passed to `survival_like`? Do the arguments have to be in alphabetical order? Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe it matters. But you could do a simple test to confirm.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to dive into the PyMC codebase to see that `logp` is called with `**data`, so the values from the dict will be passed to the correct argument, regardless of order. https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/model.py#L535

Comment: I think the line:
```return t.sum(failure * t.log(lam) - lam * value)``` 
should be:
```return t.sum(failure * (t.log(lam) - lam * value))```